# Magento - grid view doesn't work

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem with Grid View in Magento ver. 1.9.3.0.
When I'm trying to change the layout from list to grid view nothing happen.

http://alcosense.co.uk/alcosense/mode/list.html and try to change to grid.

I'm using NGINX + FastCGI and in the Nginx logs I can see this (spaced for readability):

```
682128 FastCGI sent in stderr:
    "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getReviewsCount() on a non-object in
    /var/www/alcosense/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Helper.php on line 67"
    while reading response header from upstream,
    client: 109.235.151.138,
    server: www.alcosense.co.uk,
    request: "GET /ajax/layered-navigation/catalog/category/view/id/3/requested-url/alcosense/mode/grid.html HTTP/1.1",
    upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm-alcosense.sock:",
    host: "alcosense.co.uk",
    referrer: "http://alcosense.co.uk/alcosense/mode/grid.html";;;
```

When I put this link http://alcosense.co.uk/alcosense/mode/grid.html works but just shows just only 2 products...

I don't even know where to start to fix it.

Comment: first comment the ratting block from list.phtml, and check with another theme. theme can be change from admin area.

Comment: I've removed the nginx and fastcgi tags in favour of a PHP tag since the error is caused by Magento rather than either of those two things.

Comment: Did you fix this problem already? Both of your links appear to work correctly (including toggling between list and grid view)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The client has changed something in code. He fixed it.